# Displaying Equal Space between Widgets inside Row - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, widget, flutter-dependencies

Below is the builder method that I have created to create my Widgets in flutter app :

```
Widget _buildParkingAndNagarSection(String title, Color colorBackground,
  double marginBox) {
return Expanded(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
          width: 153.5.w,
          height: 114.h,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: colorBackground,
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              border: Border.all(
                  color: Color(0xFFF1F1F1),
                  width: 1.h
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Image.asset(ic_bottom_home,
                  width: 44.w, height: 33.75.h, fit: BoxFit.fill),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
                width: 0,
              ),
              Text(
                title,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: "Poppins",
                    fontSize: 14.sp,
                    color: Color(0xFF27303E)),
                softWrap: true,
                overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ));
```

Calling it as below inside Row:

```
Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          _buildParkingAndNagarSection(
              Localization
                  .of(context)
                  .labelSaveParking,
              Color(0xFFE7F8FF), 20),
          _buildParkingAndNagarSection(
              Localization
                  .of(context)
                  .labelNavigateNagar,
              Color(0xFFFFE7EB), 10),
        ],
      ),
```

But What I have achieved is as below :

[image]

You can see there is little more space between Two Boxes. I want them as equal as it is there it's left and right side.

How ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below in Row

```
 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly
```

Also, If you face any issue please check padding and margin you applied in that widgets.

Comment: Row of methods or outside ?

Comment: you can place above code in Row. Also, you can check padding margin by applying color to respective widgets.

Answer (score 1):

`_buildParkingAndNagarSection`this method is returning an Expanded widget. So if you add 2 items in a row it will form fill up the whole space. The mainAxisAlignment will have no changes because of this. Remove the expanded widget from it and it should space evenly as expected

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for your problem

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: [
    ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: const Text(
        'Button One',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
      ),
    ),
    ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: const Text(
        'Button Two',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
      ),
    ),
    
  ],
)
```